# How to fix Angular7 - data-table Module not found error?

Tags: angular, angular7

I installed Angular7-data-table to format data in a table. I am Angular 7.2.10 version.

But Getting error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/input' in
>   'C:\Users\Desktop\Angular
>   Projects\oshop\node_modules\angular7-data-table\esm5'

Installed Bootstrap and font awesome as mentioned in the documentation. Added them in `angular.json`

angular.json

```
"styles": [
              "src/custom-theme.scss",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],

app.module.ts

import { DataTableModule } from '../../node_modules/angular7-data-table';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    DataTableModule.forRoot(),
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Have you installed @angular/material? Looks like it is missing. https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem with `node_modules/@angular/material/esm5` file import `00injectable` and `00defineInjectable` from `@angular/core`. I manually added a esm5 folder to the correct path. You can get the file via [this](https://github.com/Shenith/angular-metirial-error). Then replace the esm5 file to the correct path. Error will fixed.

Comment: Angular material version is the case. It perfectly works with v 7.3.7